# How to get a string value from the grid view

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

```
string messagestatus;

string.TryParse(
  Convert.ToString(DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "Status")), out messagestatus
);
```

I am trying to get the value of status for each row. The status is either sent or save. the error i get is string doesn't contain a definition for try parse.

I tried to get a integer and it worked perfectly how to solve the above

```
int msgid;

int.TryParse(
  Convert.ToString(DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "MsgID")), out msgid
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct, the string class doesn't have a TryParse method.

This:

```
string.TryParse(
  Convert.ToString(DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "Status")), out messagestatus
);
```

Could be done as:

```
string messageStatus= Convert.ToString(DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "Status"));
```

Answer (score 0):

can't you have code like this: ?

```
string messagestatus = String.Empty;

var objStatus = DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "Status");

if(objStatus != null)
{
  messagestatus = objStatus.ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
string messagestatus;

 if (!string.NullEmptyOrWhitespace( (DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "Status").ToString()) ? messagestatus = (DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "Status").ToString() : messagestatus = "unknown");
```

just another way of writing this basically the same